# How to add a component into page using createPage API using GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby

I am creating a documentation application for a UI library using **Gatsby**. I am able to create a markdown documentation page using Gatsby node.js `createPage` API.

However, the thing I have not figure out is **how to add a demo component into the template page too**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the guide here to add interactive component demo into your markdown documentation file, https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/